# Laravel raw select error; works in mysql

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

This following sql statement works in mysql query, but gives error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'dashboard.m.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT m.id, ....` when trying to execute the following in Laravel:

```
$this->builder = DB::select
 ("SELECT m.id, m.member_num, m.first_name, m.last_name, COUNT(s.member_id) AS members 
FROM sessions AS s 
LEFT JOIN members AS m ON s.member_id = m.id 
WHERE s.created_at >= :dateFrom 
AND s.created_at < :dateTo 
GROUP BY s.member_id",            
['dateFrom' => "date('2017-11-01')", 
'dateTo' => "date('2017-12-01')"]);
```

Can anyone see the issue considering it works correctly in mysql.

I'm simply trying to get the count of `sessions` and display the `member` details that are linked as `member_id` in `sessions`

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing in Laravel has to do with that you are selecting non aggregate columns which do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  The reason it worked in MySQL is apparently because that MySQL is running in a lax mode with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` turned off, which tolerates such non standard syntax.  I suspect you intended to use a query along these lines:

```
SELECT
    m.id, m.member_num, m.first_name, m.last_name, s.member_count
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) AS member_count
    FROM sessions
    WHERE s.created_at >= :dateFrom AND
          s.created_at < :dateTo
    GROUP BY member_id
) s
    ON m.id = s.member_id
```

Since you are aggregating over the members in the `sessions` table, and counting only a field from that table, I propose to do the aggregation in a separate subquery.  Then, join this to `members` to retrieve the full member records.

Comment: thanks for such fast answer - I've dropped your query in and while it now works, the member_count is all null ?

Comment: Hmmm...can you try running just the subquery `SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) ...` ?  What does that return? If all `member_count` are coming back `NULL` even there, then it means your data has a problem.

Comment: Another thought: How do you plan to _order_ this result set?  It could be that the few records which came back first happen to have no counts.  Perhaps you should also have an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: thank you I don't believe there is a data issue, but I will go through it thoroughly and come back soon

Comment: just so u know i'm not crazy - left side is Postman response, right side is mysql query (expecting count to be 3 as shown for this particular member) https://ibb.co/dcqfAR

Comment: This screen shot doesn't help the situation, because apparently you've ignored my above requests for more information.  So again, what happens when you run the subquery in isolation in MySQL?  Do you see members and their counts?  If you _do_ see this, then error is being introduced by the join, which means the join isn't happening properly.  This would likely be due to the data more than anything else.

Comment: ok sorry, yes I tried the subquery and it worked as I expected, thats why I posted the screenshot.  I will have another play with the join and come back

Comment: @yoyoma If you're getting `NULL` values then it means the join failed, and the members from the `members` table could not be matched to anything in the `sessions` table.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql), you could use [`ANY_VALUE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) to refer to the nonaggregated column.

```
DB::table('sessions')
    ->join('members', 'sessions.member_id', '=', 'members.id')
    ->select([
        'members.member_num',
        'members.first_name'
        'members.last_name',
        DB::raw('COUNT(sessions.member_id) AS members'),
        DB::raw('ANY_VALUE(members.id) AS id'),
    ])
    ->where([
        ['sessions.created_at', '>=', date('2017-11-01')],
        ['sessions.created_at', '<', date('2017-12-01')]
    ])
    ->groupBy('sessions.member_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks for responding, gave this a quick try and got error `ANY_VALUE does not exist`